# C++ Mixin, check if templated type implements certain mixin

Tags: c++, mixins

Given a codesnippet that looks like this, how can i write a function, that checks if a given object implements a certain mixin? I tried using pointer-casting but since they have the same base every resoult was non-null, but I am guessing there is a templated solution, but couldn't find any I could implement.

```
class Widget{
public:
  int px;
  int py;
};

template <typename Base> 
class StaticText : public Base{
public:
  std::string text; 
};

template <typename Base> 
class Alignable : public Base{
public:
  std::string alignment;
};

template <typename Base> 
class Colorable : public Base{
public:
  std::string color;
};

typedef Alignable<StaticText<Widget>> Text;

int main(){
  auto w = std::make_unique<Text>();

  // if(w == Colorable...) 
  // if(w == Alignable...) 

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm, shouldn't `if(dynamic_cast<Colorable>(ptr) != nullptr){}` work?

Comment: @Vorac `Colorable` is a template type with a (presumably unknown) argument. It would have to be `if(dynamic_cast<Colorable<T>>(ptr) != nullptr){}` but `T` could be anything.

Comment: @cdhowie indeed, and we talking mixins, so it is probably Colorable<Alignable<etc>>. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
template <template <class> class Z, class T>
class implements_mixin
{
    template <class U>
    static std::true_type  test(Z<U>* );
    static std::false_type test(... );

public:
    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T*>()));
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;        
};

template <class T>
using isColorable = implements_mixin<Colorable, T>;

// etc.
```

If there exists a `U` such that `T` inherits from `Z<U>`, we consider that mixin implemented. So `implements_mixin<Colorable, Test>::type` is `std::false_type`, but `implements_mixin<StaticText, Text>::type` is `std::true_type`.

Comment: `template <class T> using Colorable = implements_mixin<Colorable, T>;` results in `error: redefinition of 'Colorable' as different kind of symbol`. Perhaps we should call it something else like `is_Colorable`.